# Absolutely basic \csname question

Tags: macros

I was naively expecting the following code to produce the word "Jimmy" between dashes  but it produces only the dashes (commented out version also). Could someone explain (preferably one syllable words) what I'm missing, please?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

%

\begin{document}

\expandafter\def\csname v0 \endcsname{Jimmy}

%\expandafter\def\csname v0 \endcsname#1{Jimmy}

-\csname v0\endcsname-

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should try without numbers in your csname.

Comment: I actually want to define a sequence of colours in a tikz/pgf loop, e.g "\foreach\i in {1,...6}{\draw[color=\csname clr\i \endcsname]...}" or something similar. I thought characters 0-9 were allowed inside \csname ... \endcsname is that not the case? The same happens if I change "v0" to "va".

Comment: You're right, that was just a simple thought, because numbers in ordinary macro names are not really TeX's favourite. But as I posted, it works with it.

Comment: In `\csname clr\i \endcsname` there is no space after `\i` (spaces after control words are ignored during tokenization); but if you have done `\expandafter\def\csname v1 \endcsname{red}`, this *has* a space after `1`. (Note: you may see this incorrectly, but the code has a space between `1` and `\endcsname`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is the space between the name and the `\endcsname`.

[image: jimmy]

This works:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\expandafter\def\csname v0\endcsname{Jimmy}

-\csname v0\endcsname-

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a difference between `\csname v0 \endcsname` and `\csname v0\endcsname`. You defined the former, but used the latter:

> -Jimmy-

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\expandafter\def\csname v0 \endcsname{Jimmy}

-\csname v0 \endcsname-

\end{document}
```

Within `\csname` ... `\endcsname` even spaces are valid. So you'll have to match it exactly in your usage. Moreover, `\csname` ... `\endcsname` doesn't cause an error if the macro isn't defined. Instead, it *defines* it to `\relax`. Here's an example:

```
\csname v1\endcsname

\expandafter\show\csname v1\endcsname
```

The output in your `.log`/terminal is

```
\v1=\relax
```