# Calling section via csname

Tags: sectioning, csname

I want to make a command that will create a new section or subsection (or subsubsection or...) based on its argument.  Why does calling `\section` and `\subsection` via `\csname` not seem to work at all, and how can I fix it?  MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\democmd}[2]{%
  \csname #1section \endcsname{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

% Doesn't (visibly, at least) make a subsection.
\democmd{sub}{Should Make a Section}

% Also does not make a section.
\csname section \endcsname{foo}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** The fixed version is `\csname section\endcsname{foo}`, no space after section.  But why do some macros, like `textbf`, work as `\csname textbf \endcsname{foo}` **with the space**, whereas others, like `section` and `ref`, do not?

Comment: [The problem is the space before `\endcsname`.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/354798/1680)  Thanks, LaTeX!  Please, whatever you do, don't give me any hints or helpful error messages.  Also, I think there is a universal law that I can't find the helpful TeX.stackexchange post until *after* I have posted my question.

Comment: Have you tried `\@nameuse{#1section}{#2}` and of course remember `\makeatletter/other` around the definition because of the @. Though I fail to see where this can be useful.

Comment: Actually, I added a question about why `\csname textbf \endcsname` works *with the space*, which really frustrated me figuring this out.  Should this still be a duplicate?  I would appreciate input from a more experienced member of the community on this question.

Comment: Presumably robustness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Preliminary note* In the sequel, `•` denotes a space in the code, just for clarity.

The fact that sometimes `\csname•command•\endcsname` works is implementation dependent and should not be relied upon.

Of course the first space is ignored, but the second one isn't, see [Absolutely basic \csname question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354798/4427).

Why does it work for `\textbf`?

This has to do with the protection mechanism for writing to auxiliary files. A command such as `\textbf` wouldn't survive the basic writing mechanism provided by TeX, so a protection mechanism was devised to avoid it being expanded.

If you do

```
latexdef \textbf
```

from the command line you get

```latex
\textbf:
macro:->\protect \textbf  

\textbf :
\long macro:#1->\ifmmode \nfss@text {\bfseries #1}\else \hmode@bgroup \text@command {#1}\bfseries \check@icl #1\check@icr \expandafter \egroup \fi
```

On the other hand, `latexdef -s \textbf` will answer

```latex
% latex.ltx, line 4054:
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbf}{\bfseries}
```

showing that the definition of `\textbf` is rather high level.

Basically, `\textbf` is defined to expand to `\protect\textbf•` (where the space is part of the name and, guess what, `\textbf•` is defined by using `\csname`).

The command `\protect` can take several values, depending on the context. During normal typesetting its meaning is `\relax` (do nothing), but during write operations it changes to mean `\noexpand` (well, not really, but for the purpose of this answer this is not so big a lie).

The result is that during the write operation `\textbf` is first expanded to `\protect\textbf•`, which in turn will do `\noexpand\textbf•` and so the token will be written *literally*. At the end of the game, the auxiliary file will contain

```
\textbf••
```

(one space for the name and one because of how TeX writes out command names). But, when the auxiliary file is read in, TeX will just see `\textbf` followed by two spaces which will be ignored by rule.

This implementation does what it is thought for, but this fact should not be exploited. Not all commands made robust are treated this way.

Why `\section` isn't made robust? Because it's *very* unlikely it will appear in code that needs to be written to an auxiliary file. So `\section•` is not defined (under standard settings). Thus if you write

```
\csname•section•\endcsname
```

TeX will silently replace this with `\relax`. To the contrary, `\section` (without a space) is defined, so

```
\csname•section\endcsname
```

is equivalent to `\section`.