# \csname does not work with #1?

Tags: csname

I'm trying to use `\csname` to execute a command whose name depends on a variable. If I use `\csname mygametitle\tmp \endcsname` it works, but if I use instead of `\tmp` the argument `#1` it fails:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\mygametitleABC{Title for ABC}
\def\test#1{%
  \csname mygametitle#1 \endcsname%
}
\def\testb#1{%
  {%
    \def\tmp{#1}%
    \csname mygametitle\tmp \endcsname%
  }%
}

Version 1:
\test{ABC}

Version 2:
\testb{ABC}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/354798/124577

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In

```
\def\testb#1{%
  {%
    \def\tmp{#1}%
    \csname mygametitle\tmp \endcsname%
  }%                      ^^^ irrelevant
}
```

the space after `\tmp` is gobbled by the usual rules, and `\csname mygametitle\tmp \endcsname` is equivalent to `\csname mygametitle\tmp\endcsname`. But in

```
\def\test#1{%
  \csname mygametitle#1 \endcsname%
}%                    ^^^ very very relevant
```

you're adding an extra space. You should use

```
\def\test#1{%
  \csname mygametitle#1\endcsname
}%
```

Note that the `%` after the `\endcsname` are also not necessary.

Comment: Ouuu that's tricky, thanks!

Comment: @tobiasBora Spaces are ignored after numbers only when TeX is scanning for further digits, so e.g. `\csname foo\the\count0 \endcsname` and `\csname foo\the\count0\endcsname` are indeed the same. But since there are only 9 possible parameters TeX does not have to scan for further digits after `#1`, so a space after that is not ignored.